# Netflix Ribbon (via Spring Cloud) - How to mark a node down forced?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

Would it be possible to mark a node down using Ribbon client side load balancing via Spring Cloud?

I have looked into Configuration option to see if there are any inerface methods to mark a node down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it in Ribbon. See https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Working-with-load-balancers#components-of-load-balancer

The `IPing` interface determines liveliness of a node or the `ServerListFilter` interface filters servers from `ServerList`.

To add a custom `IPing` implementation ([reference](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_customizing_the_ribbon_client)) for `myservice`.

```
@Configuration
@RibbonClient(name = "myservice", configuration = CustomConfiguration.class)
public class MyAppConfiguration {
}
```

`CustomConfiguration`

```
protected static class CustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IPing ribbonPing() {
        return new CustomPingImpl();
    }
}
```

See [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_customizing_the_default_for_all_ribbon_clients) for a default for all services.